# Python 3: how to add a certain group of items to list1 from list2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, addition

How do you add a certain group of items from list1 to list2 **in one go**? (so no for loops)

So e.g.:

`list1 = [5,6,7,8]`
`list2 = [1,2,3,4]`

Now I'd like to add the **first 3 items** from list1 to list 2, so the end result would be:
`list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

I know you can remove a certain group of items from a list, but how do you move them? Thanks!

Comment: `list2.extend(list1[:3])`?

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, how would you add the last 3 items instead of the first 3?

Comment: @Lojants - There you go mate.  Just popped an answer in to address both questions.

Comment: @Lojants to get last 3 use `list2[-3:]`

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks! I already marked another answer as the correct one, but yours works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way using list slice `[:3]` and `.extend()`,

```
list1 = [5,6,7,8]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
list3 = list2[:3]
list3.extend(list1)
print(list3)
```

**DEMO:** https://rextester.com/NPD40369

To get the last 3 elements from `list2` use, `list2[-3:]`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it’s more simple than we think.  Use this to add the first three elements:

```
list2.extend(list1[:3])
```

And per your comment, use this to add the last three:

```
list2.extend(list1[-3:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), link to introduction to python, a good page for questions such as this.

Which would look like the following:

```
list1 = [5,6,7,8]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]

list2 += list1[:3]
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Remember with slices it's from but not including index, up to and including index. For example

```
list2 += list1[2:3]
```

Would be:

```
[1,2,3,4,7]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can concatenate lists

```
list2 += list1[:3]
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refrain from answering questions that have already been answered from other members, and don't add any new information. There is no need to repeat information, specially when there is already an accepted answer.

Comment: @guzmonne, it seems it was one of multiple answers almost at the same time (within 2 minutes)